# TabLayout Text size changing when multiline

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I have an issue where the text size is changing in API 23 when my tablayout title goes more than one line.  I can set my text size fine through styles.xml, but when the title goes more than one line the size seems to get ignored.

If I change the text so that it doesn't go 2 lines then the size is fine, but if I change the text so that it goes 2 lines then the size increases.

I have tried changing the text on different tabs and it happens on any of them.

My project is the Tabbed Activity/Action Bar Tabs that android creates by default.

I have been scouring google, but I can't find anything that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Include this in your dimens.xml file to set the size of the multiline text in TabLayout:

```
    <dimen name="design_tab_text_size_2line">10sp</dimen>
```

Replace 10sp with whatever matches your single line text size.

Answer (score 2):

Its using this in the TabLayout java code:

```
    // TODO add attr for these
    final Resources res = getResources();
    mTabTextMultiLineSize = res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.design_tab_text_size_2line);
    mScrollableTabMinWidth = res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.design_tab_scrollable_min_width);
```